# How to get related post by category in headless wordpress?(GraphQL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, wordpress

My problem is that object is very deep and somewhere I make a mistake that I cannot see. I want to display related post to post which someone click. I fetch date by GraphQL via Wordpress to headless cms nextjs page.

in one component I have selected categories

```
  const postCategory = post.categories.edges[0].node.name
```

and this posts with this category I want to display as related posts:

```
posts.
filter((cat) => { return(
            cat.categories.edges.map((z) => z.node.name == postCategory)
         
        )})
```

anyone make similar project and see my mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps do like this:

```
const filteredPosts = [];

for (const post in posts) {
  for (const edge in post.categories.edges) {
    if (edge.name == postCategory) {
      filteredPosts.push(post);
    }
  }
}
```

Keep things simple. Using those modern syntaxes in such a nested way only confuses people.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your query structure like this:

```
 categories {
            nodes {
              name
              posts {
                nodes {
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

and filter it like this

```
 const postsByCategory = post.categories.nodes[0].posts.nodes.slice(0, 4);

  const relatedPosts = postsByCategory.filter((relPost) => relPost.title !== post.title);
```

I wanted only 3 results after excluding the current post.

hope this helps.